# Stripe create payment and subscribe to one of the products

Tags: stripe-payments

So I'm working with stripe and I'm kinda new, here is my React code to create a payment, but I want to create a subscription to a specific product that stripe with auto charge that price every month on React.

Here is the code:

```
const payload = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      metadata: {
        "working": true
      },
      card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement),

    });
```

But I don't know how to specify that this a subscription rather than a payment one time?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is to create a PaymentMethod, no to make an actual payment. Instead I recommend doing this:

First, create a Subscription on the backend [as mentioned here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription). In Node.js it would look something like this:

```js
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: 'cus_xxx',
  items: [{ price: 'price_xxx' }],
  payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
  payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
  expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
});
```

Second, retrieve the subscription's client secret that's in `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret`, and send it to your React frontend.

Third, follow [this official guide](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) on how to use the `client_secret` to accept payments in React.

Comment: So basiclly you can't make 100% payments direct from front

Comment: i mean no fixedcharges, no subs, no products subs

Comment: do you know a similar tutorial?

Comment: You need both backend and frontend code to accept payments with Stripe. Unless you create a PaymentLink in the dashboard and use that link on your frontend: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links